# Android: download mp3 from URL

Tags: android, mp3

I need to download a mp3 file from a server URL, and then play that mp3 file.
Basically the main motive is to play a remote mp3 file, now there are two options for me, either i stream that file and play it onto media player,

or i first download it and then play it. I am still trying the first one, but with one success, so just thinking on the second alternative.

So if any help can be provided it will be great for me.......
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();  
mp.setDataSource(url_to_mp3);  
mp.prepareAsync();  
mp.start();
```

It's better to use `prepareAsync()` than `prepare()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am getting this error:11-17 20:06:36.536: ERROR/MediaPlayer(310): start called in state 4
11-17 20:06:36.566: ERROR/MediaPlayer(310): error (-38, 0)
11-17 20:06:37.086: ERROR/MediaPlayer(310): Error (-38,0)

Comment: can you provide url, from that you want to play mp3.

Comment: ooooooo Thanks user472882, i got it working, the url was broken, i was using the url form the tutorial, but then i checked it, it was broken....         Thanks..............

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Mp3player extends Activity {

    private Button buttonPlayStop;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SeekBar seekBar;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
     static final String AUDIO_PATH =
              "http://sound18.mp3slash.net/indian/abcd/[Songs.PK]%20ABCD%20-%2002%20-%20Bezubaan.mp3";
    // Here i override onCreate method.
    //
    // setContentView() method set the layout that you will see then
    // the application will starts
    //
    // initViews() method i create to init views components.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initViews();

    }

    // This method set the setOnClickListener and method for it (buttonClick())
    private void initViews() {
        buttonPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
        buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClick();

            }
        });

        try {
            playAudio(AUDIO_PATH);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                seekChange(v);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    private void playAudio(String url) throws Exception
    {
        killMediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    //    mediaPlayer.start();
    }
     private void killMediaPlayer() {
            if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    }

    // This is event handler thumb moving event
    private void seekChange(View v) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v;
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
        }
    }

    // This is event handler for buttonClick event
    private void buttonClick() {
        if (buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {
            buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));
            try {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        } else {
            buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to play a stream

```
MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(url_to_mp3);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: Hey Fedor, thanks for the response but i am getting the following error: 11-17 20:06:36.536: ERROR/MediaPlayer(310): start called in state 4
11-17 20:06:36.566: ERROR/MediaPlayer(310): error (-38, 0)
11-17 20:06:37.086: ERROR/MediaPlayer(310): Error (-38,0)

Comment: Thanks Fedor, i got it, the url was broken, i wish i could accept two answers , but i have voted it up ,thanks............